# C# login bot, .Net Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to do a simple web bot, that connects to target web page, and fills login data and than sends the information. Unfortunately I need it to be Windows XP compatible, so I am forced to use .Net Framework 4.

I know the login fill bar and password fill bar ids from firebug. Normally I would use WebBrowser with GetElementById method, but it's not an option in .Net 4. Is there any alternative how to do this in HttpWebRequest class for example?

I don't have to see anything, just need to fill in the informations and than be able to "click" in the navigation menu and download some data.

Edit: added not working afford

> ```
>     public void Send(string login, string password)
>     {
>         MyWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("username_vmlogin"); //the GetElementById is red underlined in VS 2013
>     }
> ```

It says this error:

```
Error   1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'GetElementById' and no extension method 'GetElementById' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. .NET 4 only supports XP SP3, for other SP levels you have to go back to 3.5 or even 2.0. The `WebBrowser` class is still available in .NET 4. Please clarify.

Comment: I've read that Windows XP Professional supports .Net 4, dunno if he uses SP3 or SP2. Even though WebBrowser is supported in .Net 4 there is no GetElementById function.

Comment: You have to go through the `Document` property to access `GetElementById()`... as you always did.

Comment: In document there are only 4 methods - equals, getHashCode, GetType and toString.

Comment: [I honestly don't know what you're talking about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: that's weird. as far as i was aware if something supports net 4 it should support 4.5 too since it's the same runtime?

Comment: Lets Say I have WebBrowser control named MyWebBrowser.
When I type MyWebBrowser.Document... there is no GetElementById method

Comment: What type is `MyWebBrowser`...

Comment: WEb Browser is this thing:
"<WebBrowser Name="MyWebBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="263" Margin="254,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218"/>"

Comment: Right, WPF. Not WinForms.

Comment: Well use WinForms or just RTFM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx *The Document object needs to be cast to the COM interface you are expecting.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF's WebBrowser is a wrapper over the MSHTML Web Browser control.
The WPF WebBrowser's [Document property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is an 'object', not a strongly typed HtmlDocument as in Windows Forms. As the documentation explains, `The Document object needs to be cast to the COM interface you are expecting.`.

The `Document` property implements several of the IHTMLDocumenX interfaces. `getElementById` is defined in [IHTMLDocument3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which means you'd have to write:

```
IHTMLDocument3 doc=MyWebBrowser.Document;
IHTMLElement elt=doc.getElementById("abc");
```

You can avoid casting by using a dynamic variable, eg:

```
dynamic doc=MyWebBrowser.Document;
dynamic elt=doc.getElementById("abc");
...
```

Comment: the doc.getElementById("abc"); is red underlined with an error: Error 1 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Comment: The error is explicit - you are missing some references. Either you aren't targeting .NET 4  or you moved back and forth between target frameworks and the .NET 4 references were lost, typically `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System.Core`. Actually, the complete error should be `One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?`